# Facebook module share issue

Tags: facebook, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using this code to share my app on Facebook (from the appcelerator doc) :

```
if(fb.getCanPresentShareDialog()) {
    fb.presentShareDialog({
        link:'facebook url',
        title:'app title',
        description:'app description',
        caption:'caption,
   });
} else {
    fb.presentWebShareDialog({
        link:'facebook url',
        title:' app title',
        description:'app description',
        caption:'caption,
    });
}
```

The app is shared on Facebook but without the *description* and *caption*.
I tried to change those two texts without suces. If I want to manually add a comment, it will be display on Facebook.

I suppose I'm doing something wrong but I don't see what ...

Thank's.

Comment: The Share dialog does not take any parameters besides the URL to share any more; all other data is fetched from the OG meta tags under that URL.

Comment: So the appcelerator documentation about share is no longer valid ?

Comment: If they are really calling the official FB Share dialog with those functions, then yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an answer you can accept; @CBroe is right:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

I've filed a JIRA ticket to ask for the params to be removed:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2210